# How to run the Glassfish v2.1.1 and Glassfish v3.1 at the same time on the same machine?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I have 2 projects in development; one of them deployed into the Glassfish v2.1.1, other one into Glassfish v3.1. I want to run both servers at the same time. For this, changed the default ports of Glassfish v2.1.1, 8080 and 8181 to 9090 and 9191 respectively from domain.xml. But when I started the v2.1.1 (while v3.1 is running) from Netbeans 7.0, having "`java.net.BindException: Address already in use`" exception. The question is on the topic. Your suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit : Forgot to mention that I am on Ubuntu 10.10 if it makes a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you still need to change the Glassfish settings in NetBeans.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Solved it by adding a new "Glassfish v2.x" server to Netbeans registered servers, using the same domain of my Glassfish v2.1.1 with updated ports detected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you covered all the ports Glassfish can use? How about the MQ client, do you have it enabled for example?

Try running `netstat -ab` to see which ports are still allocated to the Glassfish instance.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have changed all "`port=xxxx`" to "`port=1xxxx`" in domain.xml. In the log it says,  

`WEB0712: Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 HTTP/1.1 on 18080
WEB0712: Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 HTTP/1.1 on 18181
WEB0712: Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 HTTP/1.1 on 14848
SMGT0007: Self Management Rules service is enabled
Application server startup complete.`

Comment: But after Netbeans pops up a window with message :

`The GlassFish Application Server could not start.
More information about the cause is in the Server log file.
Possible reasons include:
 - IDE timeout: refresh the server node to see if it's running now.
 - Port conflicts. (use netstat -a to detect possible port numbers already used by the operating system.) `

Comment: `- Incorrect server configuration (domain.xml to be corrected manually) 
 - Corrupted Deployed Applications preventing the server to start.(This can be seen in the server.log file. In this case, domain.xml needs to be modified).
 - Invalid installation location.`
Where is the problem?

Comment: Hi Gabor Kulcsar. Thanks again, I want to vote your answer as "This answer is useful" but my reputation is insufficient :)

Comment: Uluk, Just accept the answer to improve your reputation. Then vote.